# Architecture and performance issue

Tags: multithreading, performance, architecture, concurrency

I have an question about architecture/performance. I'm talking about a SIP server that processes multiples client requests concurrently. I suppose that each request is treated in a dedicated thread. At the end of the process, the concerned thread log request specific infos in a file. I want to optimize the last part of processing. I mean I want to know what alternatives you propose instead of logging these infos in a file. Why? Because writing in a file after processing uses resources that I would use to process other arriving requests.

First, what do you think about the question? And, if you think that it's a "true" question (I mean that an alternative may optimize the performances), what do you propose?

I thought about logging the data into a queue and to use another process IN ANOTHER MACHINE that would read from the queue and write to a file.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: This question has a pretty broad scope, and can hardly be answered without knowing the requirements. If you need to log, the resources spent on logging are well-spent. If you don't, then don't log. To consider alternatives to logging, we need to know more about the environment and requirements. Logging the data on another machine is not necessarily cheaper, you'll have to serialize the data in both cases.

Comment: @thiton I'm talking about a SIP server. In general, a request is a call request and one thread is dedicated for this call until termination. At the end of the call (or even an error during the call), I need to keep information about the call in some place. In the current design, the call information are written into a file by this same thread. The only requirement I have is that I need to keep the call information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is *NOT* a requirement that the log is written before the request returns - i.e. the logging is not part of the atomic response - then you have the option of returning the response and just initiating the logging action.

Putting the logging data in a queue in memory seems reasonable. You can read that queue and write to disk either on the same machine or another. I would start with a thread in your app as this is easiest to implement and since the disk I/O is going to be the limiting factor, it shouldn't impact your server much.

If the log is required to be written *BEFORE* the response is returned, you still have the option of using a reliable queue like MSMQ.

Comment: No, the logging can be done at any moment after the request processing (regarding a certain limit of time). Also, what do you think about the increase in performance if the logging is done on another machine?

Comment: Is the logging required? What would happen if a response was sent and then the logging action failed for some reason?

Comment: Yes this logging is required because I need these infos for further processing. If a call request has been received by the server and terminated, I want this call to be logged.

Comment: Then whatever queue you use, it must be *RELIABLE*. Your choice of queue depends on your technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that network overhead involved in moving the logging to another machine is problably going to create more problems than it solves.  I would go with @Nicholas' solution - queue off the logs to one thread on the same machine. The queue allows slack so that occasional disk latency is mitigated and the logging thread can make its own optimizations, eg. waiting until it has a cluster-size of logs before writing.  Other stuff, like opening a new log file every day or whenever the log-file reaches a limiting size are also much easier without affecting the performance of the main server.

Even if you log on another machine, you should still queue off the logging to mitigate network latency.

If the log objects on the queue contain, say, a 'request' enumeration, (eg. ElogWrite, ElogNewFile, ElogPath, ElogShutdown), you could try both - you could queue up a request for the log thread to close its current log file and open a path to a file on a networked machine at runtime - the queue buffer would absorb the delay of doing this.